# How to fix GPG repository Error

Tags: linux, apt, upgrade, repository, chrome-book

I'm using Linux on my chromebook and recently I removed it from the development environment and installed it back. After installation, I ran `sudo apt update` but after a few seconds, it showed me this:

```
W: GPG error: https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/89 buster Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 78BD65473CB3BD13 Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
E: The repository 'https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/89 buster Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How do I fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the gpg key:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg |
sudo gpg --dearmor --yes --output /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.pgp
```

Then add  `[signed-by=//usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.pgp]` to your `sources.list` entry.

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.pgp] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt buster main
```

[Debian Wiki: Use third party.](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty#Sources.list_entry)